# jQuery - Hover after DOM change

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover, jquery-hover

With `$('#sidebar').toggleClass('small');` Im adding adding/removing specified class from `#sidebar`.

When `#sidebar` has class `small` I should be able to perform additional actions when user hover over `#sidebar.small`.

I have tried to accomplish that with code bellow:

```
$("#sidebar.small").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        alert(1);  //doesn't work
},
    mouseleave: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
    }
});
```

But that doesn't work.

How should I perform hover function on changed DOM element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the jquery hover method to do this: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Update:
Sorry noticed one other thing... when you originally set your event handler, does #sidebar have the css tag or not?  The way your code is written, if it doesn't, it will try to attach to the element $("#sidebar.small"), so if the css tag is not there it won't attach to anything.

I think you want more like this:

```
$("#sidebar").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
       if($('#sidebar').hasClass('small')) {
           alert(1);
       }
    }
});
```

Update again for a typo, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Jquery only binds the handlers for the found elements **at the time of binding**.

The solution is to rebind the appropriate handlers when you add the class.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwon4qkj/1/)

code from the fiddle:

```
$('#foo').click(function(){
    $('<span></span>')
    .text('A Span')
    .appendTo('#container');
});

$('#bar').click(function(){
   $('span').first().toggleClass('small');
   bindHover();    
})

function bindHover(){
    $('span.small').unbind('hover'); // Avoid re-binding something
    $('span.small').hover(function(){
        alert('a')
    });
}

bindHover();
```

Comment: I think for this to work, you need to only add the bindHover on $('#bar').click when it isn't already there... otherwise you are adding additional bindings and you'll get more then 1 alert.

Comment: But honestly my answer is way too complicated. I thought OP needed to do this for dynamic elements. The better solution for the single, always-present `#sidebar` div is to bind once to hover or mouseenter, and test the class in the handler, like you demonstrated in your answer.

Comment: I assumed that based on the identifier sidebar there aren't multiple, but I have used your pattern as well for dynamic elements, so yeah, it really depends what OP is going for.